# Clear an optional variable in Swift

Tags: swift, variables, declaration

If I declare an empty image:

```
var myImage: UIImage?
```

and then give it a value:

```
myImage = UIImage(named: "drawing.png")
```

how can I later remove that value, returning it to its original empty state?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var myImage: UIImage?
```

Is basically short hand for making a `UIImage` point to `nil` automatically.

So to reset it back to the original value say:

```
myImage = nil
```

Answer (score 2):

Set its value back to nil like this

```
myImage = nil
```

Comment: @SapphireBrick. Sure. But looking at the timestamps, this one was the first.

Answer (score 2):

`Optional` is an `enum` type in Swift; it has two cases:

```
enum Optional<T> : NilLiteralConvertible {
    case None
    case Some(T)
    ...
}
```

By assigning an image to your `Optional<UIImage>`, you have implicitly specified `.Some(image)`. To clear it, you can use `.None`. But since `Optional` also conforms to `NilLiteralConvertible`, you can use the simpler and clearer **`nil`**.

Answer (score -1):

Declare it as `AnyHashable`, if there's a need to change the data type of the reference:

```
var x: AnyHashable
myImage = UIImage(named: "drawing.png")
```